# python-pptx - Adding the content box in a "Title and Content" slide

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm using the pptx module to create a PowerPoint "Title and Content" slide.

```
prs = Presentation()
mySlide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[1])
```

I can "address" the title with either "title" attribute or the "placeholder[0]" attribute.

```
# These both work.
titlePlaceholder = mySlide.shapes.title
titlePlaceholder = mySlide.shapes.placeholders[0]
```

However, the only way I can figure out to "address" the "content box" on the "Title and Content" slide is with the "placeholder[1]" attribute.

```
contentPlaceholder = mySlide.shapes.placeholders[1]
```

Is there another way to "address" the content box?  Is there something like a "content" attribute?

```
# I'd like to use something similar to this.
contentPlaceholder = mySlide.shapes.content
```

Incidentally, my apologies in advance for any typos in my code examples.  For corporate reasons, I can't access StackOverflow on the same system I do my Python programming, so I can't cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't. You have to do it by a process of elimination. In my code I pick the first one after the title - though sometimes I choose to use that one as a subtitle.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Since there was a "title" attribute, it seemed reasonable that there would be something similar to a "content" attribute.  I tried checking but didn't find anything.  However, at that point, I thought I might be missing it.  It's good to have confirmation that what I'm looking for doesn't exist.  That way, I don't have to waste any more time looking for it.